# How to plot the perimeter of an ellipse where the variable is its eccentricity?

Tags: plotting, special-functions, variable

I'm basically just trying to plot a function where the x value is the eccentricity of an ellipse and the y value its perimeter.

I've tried first defining the eccentricity

```
m == ((a^2 - b^2)^(1/2))/a
```

and then trying something like

```
Plot[4*a*EllipticE[m], {m, 0, 5}]
```

since `4*a*EllipticE[m]` would be the perimeter. Any ideas on how to try plot the graph with such a variable?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You just need to specify a value for `a`. There's a couple of ways you could do that depending on what you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you - I set the value for b to 1 in all cases and now I'm looking at a from 1 to another set value

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

m[a_, b_] = ((a^2 - b^2)^(1/2))/a;
```

**EDIT:** Corrected formula used for perimeter in plot

```
perim[a_, b_] = Perimeter[Disk[{0, 0}, {b, a}]]

(* 4 a EllipticE[1 - b^2/a^2] *)

ParametricPlot[{m[a, 1], perim[a, 1]}, {a, 1, 10}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ 
  {"eccentricity, m", "perimeter"}), 
 PlotRange -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{m, p, a}, ColorData["Rainbow"][a]], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {1, 10}}, LegendLabel -> Style["a", 14]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you missed the square... see  Edit in my answer.

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

To plot the circumference of an ellipse with b as length of semi-minor axis  = 1 as function of a (semi-major axis) use

```
b = 1; Plot[4*a*EllipticE[(Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]/a)^2], {a, 0, 10}, 
AxesLabel -> {"a", "circumference"}]
```

Remember to square the parameter (Mathematica convention).
For a = 1 the value is 2π, for a = 10 >> b the value is around 2 times 2 times 10 = 40.

[image]

Edit:

It is not easy to see the effect of squaring the parameter, it is most pronounced at small a:

```
b = 1; Plot[{4*a*EllipticE[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]/a], 
4*a*EllipticE[(a^2 - b^2)/a^2], 
Pi*((a + b) + (3*(a - b)^2)/(10*(a + b) + 
Sqrt[a^2 + 14*a*b + b^2]))}, {a, 1, 2}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Magenta, {Black, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

The blue line shows the incorrect perimeter, the graph in magenta is the correct one (compared with Ramanujan's approximation of the elliptic perimeter, black dashed curve, taken from Wikipedia)